# Running into HttpMessageNotReadableException calling getForEntity() restTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am writing a test that calls controller that returns a List of objects. However, my restTemplate [getForEntity()](https://github.com/YADAAB/UdacityAssignments/blob/master/course2/dogrest/src/test/java/com/udacity/course2/dogrest/web/DogRestIntegTest.java#L33) call returns the error -

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [interface java.util.List] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

Controller returns [list of Strings](https://github.com/YADAAB/UdacityAssignments/blob/master/course2/dogrest/src/main/java/com/udacity/course2/dogrest/web/DogController.java#L48) for any request coming its way. I do not understand below error message when controller returns an ArrayList

> Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token

How do I fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code of your call for getForEntity().

Comment: Its here(already added as link in the question) - https://github.com/YADAAB/UdacityAssignments/blob/master/course2/dogrest/src/test/java/com/udacity/course2/dogrest/web/DogRestIntegTest.java#L33

Comment: Check the url via curl if you really get a List object.

Comment: Had to change return type from List to String and it seemed to have done the work here. Also, switched restTemplate to call exchange()